# DependencyProperty-like functionality on an AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, wpf, angularjs, user-controls, angularjs-directive

I currently work as a WPF developer and I'm teaching myself the basics of AngularJS.  In WPF, I'm used to separating my UI into isolated pieces using custom `UserControls`, and then communicating with these pieces by binding to the various `DependencyProperties` I choose to expose on each `UserControl`.

From the small amount of research I've done on AngularJS, the closest thing Angular has to a `UserControl` is a `directive`.  However, I haven't found any way to replicate the function of WPF's `DependencyProperties` on an Angular `directive`.

Is there something I'm missing?  Or perhaps I'm inappropriately trying to force my WPF design paradigms onto AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use html attributes to link scope variables to your directives.

I suggest reading this walk through: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive